# Toggle background div color

Tags: jquery, css

I was trying to follow another example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/HABdx/3/) and have a few questions about my code below.

1. Why does the color get applied to only the area around the text instead of the entire div?
2. Why is the color applied to all divs on click and not removed when clicking an adjacent div?

**html**

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="menu"> <a href="#1" class="one"><div class="box">A</div></a>
 <a href="#1" class="one"><div class="box">B</div></a>
 <a href="#1" class="one"><div class="box">C</div></a>
 <a href="#1" class="one"><div class="box">D</div></a>

    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var obj = {};
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".one").click(function () {
        var text = $(this).find(".box").html();

        obj.var1 = text;
        //alert(obj.var1);
        //return false;

       $('box').removeClass('selected');
       $(this).addClass('selected')
    });
});
```

**CSS**

```
#menu div {
    text-align:center;
    display:inline-block;
}
div.box {
    position: relative;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    background: #fff;
    color: #000;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid;
}

div.box:hover {
    cursor: hand;
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: .5;
}

.selected {
    background : #000000;
}
```

Comment: It seems to be working fine to me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.The color is only applied to the div. You should change your css to target the a.

Changing this

```
#menu div { ... }
div.box { ... }
div.box:hover { ... }
```

to this

```
#menu a { ... }
a.one { ... }
a.one:hover { ... }
```

2.The color is not remove because you forgot the . (dot) before the selector.

```
$('box').removeClass('selected');

$('.box').removeClass('selected');
```

I would also recommend not having div inside a for correct validation. You could use a span with style="display:block" or style="display:inline-block" as an alternative.

Here is a jsFiddle working example : http://jsfiddle.net/A7f94/

Answer (score 2):

this is wrong:

`var text = $(this).find(".box").html();`
`...`
`$('box').removeClass('selected');`

it should be: 
`var text = $(this).find(".box");`
`...`
`$(".one").removeClass('selected');`

useful links:

http://api.jquery.com/find/

http://api.jquery.com/html/